# Fill enum with RBGA values

Tags: c++, enums

I want to fill my enum with RBGA values. For example:

```
enum Colors
{
    COLOR_BLACK,
    COLOR_WHITE,
    COLOR_RED,
    COLOR_GREEN,
    COLOR_DARKBLUE,
};

Colors[COLOR_BLACK] = CColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

My question is: In which way do I have to declare CColor to be able to fill my enum with 4 floats?

Comment: So, you want to have a table of those 5 colours as `CColor` values?

Comment: Yes. I don't want to use an array. I want to be able to use CColor to hold these 4 floats and be able to work with them in a function. Whole  code of my class I'm looking forward to use. http://pastebin.com/y7YK5rNj

Answer (score 3):

You need a array of `CColor`to do so:

```
struct CColor
{
    CColor( float r, float g, float b, float a )
        : red(r), green(g), blue(b), alpha(a) {}
    float red, green, blue, alpha;
};

enum Colors
{
    COLOR_BLACK,
    COLOR_WHITE,
    COLOR_RED,
    COLOR_GREEN,
    COLOR_DARKBLUE,
};

CColor mycolors[] = {
    CColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // COLOR_BLACK
    CColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), // COLOR_WHITE
    CColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // COLOR_RED
    CColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // COLOR_GREEN
    CColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)  // COLOR_DARKBLUE
};

CColor GetColor( Colors col ) { return mycolors[col]; }

CColor red = GetColor(COLOR_RED);
```

This works, because enums have ascending numbers, starting with `0`.

Comment: May need a name of that too?

Comment: You are missing a `;` at the end of the array definition.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but with an array I can not use my enum like I have to. See http://pastebin.com/y7YK5rNj for the whole class.

Comment: I think that you should add the `struct CColor` definition, too. Maybe the OP is confused about this one.